# Screen disappears on inserting any text in Input field

Tags: reactjs

When I insert any text in input field, screen disappears, I am new to UI, learning ReactJs, help me out please.

```
import React from 'react';

    class InputChange extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state={
                input:''
            }
      }

       updateState = (text) => {
        this.setState({input: text});
    }

      render(){

          return(
                <div>
                    <div>Input:{this.state.input}</div>
                    <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.updateState} />
                    </div>
                </div>`
          );
      }
    }
    export default InputChange;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `event.target.value`...:

```
class InputChange extends React.Component {
  state = { input: '' };

  updateState = event => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Input:{this.state.input}</div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.input}
            onChange={this.updateState}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default InputChange;
```

More info in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html